# Google Chrome running in background without my knowledge

Tags: python, google-chrome, debugging, selenium-chromedriver

Ever since I started using Python Selenium and windows task manager to automate a python script to scrape the web using Google chrome I am having this issue where even though I haven't opened Chrome it still shows in the task manager and uses 60-70% CPU. This is slowing my laptop significantly and I can't seem to solve it. If I end task Chrome then it fixes but randomly after some time chrome again pops up in task manager slowing my laptop. If anyone has a solution to this it would be a great help if you can help me.
[image: Screen shot of task manager]

Comment: you also have some python idle running that doesn't appear in the taskbar. And Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Did you follow a howto-guide? If so, can you share the URL?

Comment: Python is running because of Vscode and I don't know why Microsoft edge is running. And I used this tutorial to start (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-n40rB1XaJ0ak1bemvlqumQ&index=1)